# Determine List Length To Update CSV File Correctly

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I have information and I need to update a CSV file with the information. The information is in a list, but the length of the list can vary. I need to update the CSV file to have all of the information, but if the list length is less than 5, the CSV file should have some empty values.
Here is my CSV file:

```
Name,1,2,3,4,5
Adam,,,,,
```

The variable *listBios* is defined earlier, and all it contains is different information.
Here is my code:

```
with open("testing copy.csv", "w", newline = '') as wfile:
    headers = ["Name", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    csv_writer = DictWriter(wfile, fieldnames = headers)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerow({
        "Name": "Adam",
        '1': listBios[0],
        '2': listBios[1],
        '3': listBios[2],
        '4': listBios[3],
        '5': listBios[4]
    })
```

This throws the error:

```
'4': listBios[3],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because the list *listBios* has a length of 3, not 4. How could I have it detect how many items are in the list, and only add that many to the CSV so I don't get an error?

Thank you so much,

Adam

Comment: The issue is most probably in the `listBios` so you need to post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `iter()` on `listBios` then call `next()` with a default value:

```
iterBios = iter(listBios)


with open("testing copy.csv", "w", newline = '') as wfile:
    headers = ["Name", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    csv_writer = DictWriter(wfile, fieldnames = headers)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerow({
        "Name": "Adam",
        '1': next(iterBios, ''),
        '2': next(iterBios, ''),
        '3': next(iterBios, ''),
        '4': next(iterBios, ''),
        '5': next(iterBios, '')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the length of the list, use the `len()` function.
For example:

```
ex = ['dog', 'cat', 'test']
length_of_ex = len(ex)
print(length_of_ex)
```

output:

```
3
```

Comment: I know how to do that, but how do I change how many columns I write to based on the length of listBios?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary list that is always 5 in length. If length of `listBios` is less than 5 then add empty string elements to the temporary list using `[''] * (5 - len(listBios))`:

```
with open("testing copy.csv", "w", newline = '') as wfile:
    headers = ["Name", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    csv_writer = DictWriter(wfile, fieldnames = headers)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_list = listBios + [''] * (5 - len(listBios))
    csv_writer.writerow({
        "Name": "Adam",
        '1': csv_list[0],
        '2': csv_list[1],
        '3': csv_list[2],
        '4': csv_list[3],
        '5': csv_list[4]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.zip_longest`.  This is similar to `zip` on two iterables, except that instead of stopping after the shorter one comes to an end, it keeps going until the longer one does, using the fill value (defaults to `None`) after the end of the shorter sequence.

So for example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

headers = ["Name", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
listBios = ["blah", "stuff", "whatever"]

vals = ["Adam"] + listBios  # list of all the values including the name

print(dict(zip_longest(headers, vals, fillvalue='')))
```

gives:

```
{'Name': 'Adam', '1': 'blah', '2': 'stuff', '3': 'whatever', '4': '', '5': ''}
```

Just pass that dictionary to `writerow`.

If there is any possibility that your `vals` list might be *longer*, then you might want to slice it so that it is no longer than `headers`. This will not affect the output in the case that it is the same length or shorter.

```
dict(zip_longest(headers, vals[:len(headers)], fillvalue=''))
```

---

### Addendum: using zip

It turns out also that if you use plain `zip` in place of `zip_longest`, giving a dictionary where the headers are truncated rather than the values padded, i.e.:

```
print(dict(zip(headers, vals)))
```

gives

```
{'Name': 'Adam', '1': 'blah', '2': 'stuff', '3': 'whatever'}
```

then when you pass that dictionary to `writerow`, you get the same effect, because `DictWriter` knows to fill in any missing cells with empty strings.  So you could use that instead, and then you do not need to import the `itertools` module.

There is still a potential advantage with `itertools.zip_longest`, that you could specify a different `fillvalue`, for example if you wanted `'-'` in the otherwise empty columns.